# Android buttons width dynamic adjustment through code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

consider the scenario if i have 3 button, then first two button should be side by side in  50% of the layout and  third button should take remaining 50% width left in the layout dynamically. If there are 5 button then layout will be divided in 33.33% per each row where 1st,2nd button and 3rd,4rd button  will be side by side with width of 16% each and last i.e 5th one should have a width of 33.33%.

```
 <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="300dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="200dp" 
android:padding="5dp"
 android:shrinkColumns=""
 android:stretchColumns="" > 
<Button android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="New Button" 
android:id="@+id/button" 
android:layout_marginTop="220dp"/>
 </TableLayout>






   mTlayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
         int last = mTextofButton.length;
         int i = 0; 
        while (i < mTextofButton.length) { if (i != last) { if (i % 2 == 0) { tr = new TableRow(this);
         mTlayout.addView(tr);
         } 
        Button btn = new Button(this);
         btn.setText(mTextofButton[i]); 
        btn.setId(i);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
System.out.println("v.getid is:- " + v.getId());
 } }); 
 tr.addView(btn); i++; } else { //need to wr }
```

Comment: please post your xml here.....

Comment: i have to generate it from code so no xml available . I will get arraylist of nos buttons and text which need to be adjusted side by side depending whether the are even or odd

Comment: than put your code here .....

Comment: <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_marginTop="220dp"/>
    </TableLayout>

Comment: mTlayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
 int last = mTextofButton.length;
 int i = 0;
 while (i < mTextofButton.length) {

  if (i != last) {
   if (i % 2 == 0) {
    tr = new TableRow(this);
    mTlayout.addView(tr);
   }
   Button btn = new Button(this);
   btn.setText(mTextofButton[i]);
   btn.setId(i);

   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     System.out.println("v.getid is:- " + v.getId());
    }
   });
   tr.addView(btn);
   i++;

  } else {
   //need to wr
  }

Comment: bro edit your question and put there

Comment: try Linear-layout instead of TableLayout because in linearLayout you make weight for View in percentage .

Comment: is it possible for u to give me some dummy code which i can see. this is first time i am doing it.

Comment: use this video it clear your concept :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMksRBvYG28

Comment: use this for programming :- http://sawchenko.net/blog/android/2013/09/01/Setting-Layout-Programmatically/     and enjoy coding .......